# The stationery tag is stationary

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We have a tag [stationary](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stationary) which is applied to just one, closed [question](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/9907/best-and-highest-use-of-last-years-phonebook).

The tag, as used, is mis-spelled, it should clearly be [stationery](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stationery).

Could we please either edit the tag to correct it or delete the question so that the tag disappears as no longer used?

Comment: Synonymising works.  There are precedents for synonymising typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I've merged the two tags and have made [stationary](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stationary) a synonym of [stationery](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stationery).