# The tags stationary and stationery do not mean the same thing

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I have been looking at tags and synonyms lately (can you tell?).

While the tags [stationery](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stationery) and [stationary](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stationary) may sound the same, they have very different meanings. Currently, [stationary](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stationary) ([which means not moving](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/stationary)) is a synonmym to [stationery](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stationery) ([which means related to paper products](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/stationery)).

I saw where the [tags were made synonyms](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2623/the-stationery-tag-is-stationary) due to user confusion. I think this might lead to more confusion, especially by people who know the difference.

If the tags are split, we (or I) should update the description to match the definitions.

Comment: I agree that the correction should be made regardless of any reason it happened. Using misspelling might work in website keywords for helping search engine optimization but should be correctly defined here in tags in a move to upgrade the quality of the site contributions by example. It mocks efforts to edit questions and answers for accuracy and clarity. It would be preferable to correct an incorrect tag when/if it occurs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was initially done because the [stationery](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stationery) tag was being misspelled as [stationary](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stationary). I agree that they do not mean the same thing, but just think about it, when would a question on this website really need the [stationary](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stationary) tag? Therefore, I think we should keep [stationary](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stationary) as a duplicate of [stationery](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stationery).

Comment: Agreed. +1.....

Comment: Seems like a rather messy solution to me but maybe I just like English too much.